# Repeated measures MANOVA

Tags: repeated-measures, multivariate-analysis, manova

I have to analyze a data set of the following format

[image]

Here the subjects receiving the two treatments are different

- For this I thought of using a repeated measures MANOVA. Is this a
  correct choice?To do this should the variables BMI, Heart Rate,
  Glucose Level be uncorrelated?
- Say if I want to see if there is any relationship between BMI and
  Glucose level. How can I do this? Should I do it separately for the
  two treatments?
- Like in uni variate case if I am to draw a scatter plot between Heart
  Rate and Glucose separately for the two treatments how can I achieve
  it here, as age is a repeated measure. Should I consider the mean
  value for each subject for BMI and heart rate and then draw a scatter plot?

Comment: You have to be precise about the question you want to answer. It seems there was no predefined question here to start with and you want to do exploratory analysis. You can, for example, check for relation between glucose and BMI or heart rate without taking into account treatment group or age. If you want to assess their effect also, you should clearly write what exactly you want to determine. Best would be to discuss one question in one post.